# Is the phrase "lurking suspicion" in this context humour?

Tags: short-stories, mark-twain

I am reading the short story "The Notorious Jumping Frog of Calaveras County" by Mark Twain. I was wondering if the author's usage of the phrase "lurking suspicion" in the first paragraph is an instance of humour?

> In compliance with the request of a friend of mine, who wrote me from the East, I called on good-natured, garrulous old Simon Wheeler, and inquired after my friend's friend, Leonidas W. Smiley, as requested to do, and I hereunto append the result. I have a lurking suspicion that Leonidas W. Smiley is a myth; that my friend never knew such a personage; and that he only conjectured that, if I asked old Wheeler about him, it would remind him of his infamous Jim Smiley, and he would go to work and bore me nearly to death with some infernal reminiscence of him as long and tedious as it should be useless for me. If that was the design, it certainly succeeded.

Comment: Welcome to the site! When possible, please try to include quotes rather than images; they are easier to index for search engines and easier to parse for people using screen readers. With old stories like Mark Twain's, you can usually find the text online (e.g. at [Project Gutenberg](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/15585/15585-h/15585-h.htm#THE_CELEBRATED_JUMPING_FROG_OF_CALAVERAS_COUNTY)), so that you can copy and paste the relevant paragraph rather than typing it by hand.